# The app gets force closed

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am building an app which opens the google map activity when a button(actually an image) is pressed in my app.
The code compiles, But the app gets forced closed

JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=workshop%20near%20me");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }

            }
);

}
```

}

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Added meta data in mainfest.xml and complie google-play-service-versio:8.+ added in build gradle. Now gradle shows 3 errors

Answer (score 1):

I just solved. The cleaned the gradle build and rebuild gradle after adding complie android-play-service: 8.+

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:
"If the system cannot identify an app that can respond to the intent, your app may crash. For this reason, you should first verify that a receiving application is installed before you present one of these intents to a user."

Try verifying that an app is installed that can handle the intent first:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + Uri.encode("workshop near me"));
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                   startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Like Jesse Buss mentions above it would be really helpful to see your stack trace